# Weird bug with SVG in Link in Chrome

Tags: html, css, svg

I wrote some CSS for underline animations when hovering over a link, and everything works fine in Firefox, but in Chrome I noticed a bug (?):

I have some SVG social icons wrappend in an `<a></a>` with a `border-radius` of `50%` to display them as circles. When I hover over **my other `<a>` tags** however, the SVG icon flickers and gets a *square* background.
I created a small example on [codepen](http://codepen.io/cmichel/pen/VmZQrR).

Why does this happen - the text link and the SVG link should not influence each other, no? Does anyone have an idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your inline styles on the svg element. 
You have position absolute on the svg, and that I think, is what is causing most of your issues.

Comment: You are also referring to a wrong class in your css, in your pen.

Comment: Thanks removing the position absolute inline style worked!